# Python regex inserting big string full of data into SQL database

Tags: python, sql, regex

I would like to take a gigantic string, chop it up and put it into an SQL table in order.

So far I have tried using regex to split up the string, getting the values I want and trying insert them into the table like so.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('PP.DB')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE apps (DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate, PSCOmputerName, RunspaceId)''')

# Split up string based on new lines
bigStringLines = re.split(r'\\r\\n', myBigString)

for line in bigStringLines:
    values = re.split(":", line)
    stmt = "INSERT INTO mytable (\"" + values[0] + "\") VALUES (\"" + values[1] + "\");"
    c.execute(stmt)
```

However it looks like this inside the SQL database

```
DisplayName          DisplayVersion   Publisher        InstallDate  PSComputerName   RunspaceId
Installed program 1  
                     1.2.3.123        
                                      CyberSoftware    
                                                       20121115     
                                                                    Computer1        
                                                                                     b37da93e9c05
Installed program 2
                      4.5.6.456        
                                        MicroSoftware    
                                                       20160414     
                                                                    Computer2        
                                                                                     b37da93e9c06
```

Idealy I would like it to look like this inside the database:

```
DisplayName          DisplayVersion   Publisher        InstallDate  PSComputerName   RunspaceId
Installed program 1  1.2.3.123        CyberSoftware    20121115     Computer1        b37da93e9c05
Installed program 2  4.5.6.456        MicroSoftware    20160414     Computer2        b37da93e9c06
```

Here's what the main structure of the string looks like:

```
DisplayName    : Installed program 1
DisplayVersion : 1.2.3.123
Publisher      : CyberSoftware
InstallDate    : 20121115
PSComputerName : Computer1
RunspaceId     : 38ff5be0-da11-4664-97b1-b37da93e9c05

DisplayName    : Installed program 2
DisplayVersion : 2.2.2.147
Publisher      : CyberSoftware
InstallDate    : 20140226
PSComputerName : Computer1
RunspaceId     : 38ff5be0-da11-4664-97b1-b37da93e9c05
```

Just for a bit of extra background info, this will be part of a bigger program that queries what apps are installed on a large group of computers. For testing I'm just using SQLite however plan to move it to MySQL in the future.

If anyone know what I'm doing wrong or has any suggestions I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You're doing an insert for every line in the text file, not for every *record* in the file. Only do an insert for every record. If this is consistent, then fill variables and insert after filling `RunSpaceId` or a blank line, then clear all variables (or use a dictionary, probably easier) and iterate to the next record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing an insert for every line in the text file, not for every *record* in the file. Only do an insert for every record. If this is consistent, then fill variables and insert after filling `RunSpaceId` or a blank line, then clear all variables (or use a dictionary, probably easier) and iterate to the next record. Something like:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('PP.DB')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE apps (DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate, PSCOmputerName, RunspaceId)''')

# Split up string based on new lines
bigStringLines = re.split(r'\\r\\n', myBigString)
record = {}

for line in bigStringLines:
    if line.startswith("DisplayName"):
        record["DisplayName"] = re.split(":", line)[1]  # or find index of colon and use negative slice notation from end of string
    elif line.startswith("DisplayVersion"):
        record["DisplayVersion"] = re.split(":", line)[1]
    # and so on for all values....
    elif line.strip() == "":  # blank line = end of record (or use `RunSpaceId as trigger once populated)
        stmt = "INSERT INTO mytable (DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate, PSCOmputerName, RunspaceId) VALUES ({DisplayName}, {DisplayVersion}, {Publisher}, {InstallDate}, {PSCOmputerName}, {RunspaceId});".format(**record)  # adjust as needed depending on python version
        c.execute(stmt)
        record = {}  # reset for next record
```

And PS, if this is in a text file, this can all be accomplished without using RegEx at all (and I recommend this). There is no reason to read the entire file into memory if it is a local flat file.

Comment: Thanks for the help Dan :)